# XMP causing POST safe mode - ASUS ROG STRIX Z370-F Gaming

Tags: windows, memory, motherboard, bios, overclocking

I have just installed a new setup and wanted to try the installed `XMP` profile for `ASUS ROG STRIX Z370-F Gaming` motherboard. However when I activate `XMP` the computer fails to start and [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) into `safe mode`. BIOS is the latest `Version 0606`.

I have two ram sticks and they are connected to `DIMM_A2` and `DIMM_B2` as recommended in the [manual](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z370-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_Manual/).

My setup:

```
CPU : Intel LGA 1151 i7-8700K
Motherboard : ROG STRIX Z370-F GAMING
DRAM : Corsair Vengeance LPX Black 32GB (2x16GB) / 4000MHz / DDR4 / CL19 / CMK32GX4M2F4000C19
Power : Corsair HX850 850W
Cooling: Cooler Master Hyper 212 Evo CPU cooler
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
```

ASUS own setup for testing 4000 MHz:

```
CPU : Intel LGA 1151 i7-8700K
Motherboard : ROG STRIX Z370-F GAMING
DRAM : CORSAIR CMK32GX4M4B4000C19R Ver. 4.31
Power : Corsair AX1500i
Water-cooling : Corsair H115i
OS: Windows 10
```

In the description they say: `Improved Stability and Overclocking - With all slots populated`. Will the system be more stable if I populate all `DIMM` slots? Never heard of this before. If they supported Quad-channel I would understand it but according to their specification they use `Dual Channel Memory Architecture`.

https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z370-F-GAMING/specifications/

https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z370-F-GAMING/

Settings changed when enabling `XMP`:

[image]

Safe mode message:

[image]

Comment: "Settings changed when enabling XMP:" - Of course memory related configurations will be reset, by enabling XMP, you're telling your system to query the memory for what configurations it supports.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes of course. The picture is added so that settings can be viewed by others and see if something looks out of the ordinary.

Comment: As the modules are modules rated at 4000 and as such are unlikely in the supported vendor module list you probably won't be able to run them at their rated speed. It's likely that you will be able to run them at 2933. It's a known issue that Ryzen is very finicky when it comes to modules and speed. Higher speeds usually seem to work better with fewer modules.

Comment: @Seth Thanks I will check that out. I'm using `Intel LGA 1151 i7-8700K` CPU, not `AMD Ryzen`. :)

Comment: Z ... X whatever! ;) Sorry about that, but it's probably the same for Intel, though they do seem to have better compatibility. Did you try to explicitly set the speed below whats on the box to see at what speed you're able to POST?

Comment: @Seth ;) Yepp I tried that, I'm now running at `3400MHz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer but at least it is something, thanks Seth for pointing me in the right direction!

I started by downloading the Asus Memory QVL (Qualified Vendors Lists) for the motherboard.

https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z370-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_QVL/

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/ROG_STRIX_Z370-F_GAMING/Z370-4DIMM-Memory-QVL_20180103.pdf?_ga=2.148090164.200533471.1515708612-140276240.1515708612

In there I noticed that my modules were not present (obviously) but also that other 16 GB sticks were used at `3466MHz` at most. I then set `XMP` again but manually set the RAM back to `3466MHz` instead of `4000MHz`. Now my PC booted but Windows crashed after a few seconds. I then set the memory to `3400MHz` and now I'm running `Windows` normally. It is not `4000MHz`  but a lot more than the fail safe `2133MHz`.